# pre() in es6 not running as expected?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6, postman, mongoose-schema

Postman is returning error whenever i include this pre() function,
it returns an error else its working and everything is getting stored in db using mongodb.
Is there something wrong in ES6 format that i have used or any other?

Below is the code :

// userschema is the name of the schema // 
// SALT_I = 10 //

```
userSchema.pre('save', next => {
    if (this.isModified('password')) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_I, (err, salt) => {
            if (err) 
                return next(err)
            bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                if (err)
                    return next(err)
                this.password = hash
                next()
            })
        })
    } else
        next()
})
```

here is the postman error:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "err": {}
}
```

and it is as i am making a post request using the function:

```
app.post('/api/users/register', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)
    user.save((err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err })
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            userdata: data
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: "Postman is returning error" - Why are you keeping the error message secret?

Comment: i have edited it in!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ES6 spread operator but ES5 syntax works just fine:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    const user = this
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_I, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("inside gensalt if")
                return next(err)
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("inside bcrpt hash")
                    return next(err)
                }
                user.password = hash
                next()
            })
        })
    } else
        next()
})
```